# How to fix a table size in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Is there a way or an option available in `MySQL` to fix the size of a table? Which will work as a circular buffer and overwrites the old data whenever a new data gets inserted. This is useful when an application is collecting the stats and a month old data becomes no longer useful.

I know programmatically this is possible but I don't want to do that, hence this request.

BTW, this is similar to a feature called [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) in MongoDb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to throw away last month's data, just use the day-of-the-month in your primary key.  Last month's "26" will be overwritten by next month's "26".

Comment: I find no such automatic operation exists in MySQL but I have used your approach to build such ability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a specific option to achieve this, however, you could make it work using a simple trigger. (I know it's a programmatic way but I believe it is the only pure-sql option in mysql)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `CapTable` BEFORE INSERT ON `MyTable` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    SET @NumRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable); 
    IF @NumRows > 1000 THEN
        DELETE FROM MyTable ORDER BY id LIMIT 1; 
        /* delete the oldest row, assuming id is auto_increment */
    END IF;

END;
```